# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, while using RecyclerView an an adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Ok, so let me tell this beforehand... For this issue, i have searched more than 28 similar stack overflow questions...invested/wasted more than 2 days, still unable to debug what exactly is the issue...

Everything goes fine, shows the build is successful, but the layout never gets populated with the view item (as expected from the adapter)...

In the Logcat, it shows,

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

(twice)

Any help would be appreciated, as no clue in other answer helps me out...after trying for many hours, i am now giving up...(it to the developer community)

Here's my code...The Activity,

```
    List<ChatNode> chatNodeList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView channels = findViewById(R.id.listviewChannel);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    channels.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //channels.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    //channels.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));


    ChatNode chatNode1 = new ChatNode("Hare", "This was last chat", "2:13", "3", "1");
    chatNodeList.add(chatNode1);
    ChatNode chatNode2 = new ChatNode("P 11", "This was last chat", "2:13", "3", "1");
    chatNodeList.add(chatNode2);
    ChatNode chatNode3 = new ChatNode("Q 12", "This was last chat", "2:13", "3", "1");
    chatNodeList.add(chatNode3);
    ChatListAdapter chatListAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(chatNodeList);

    channels.setAdapter(chatListAdapter);
    //chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is my ChatListAdapter

```
public class ChatListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<ChatNode> chatNodes;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name, lastchat, lastchattime, chatunread;
    ImageView dp;
    MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastChat_Name);
        lastchat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastChat_Message);
        lastchattime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastChat_MessageDate);
        chatunread = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_unread);
        dp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dp);
    }
}

ChatListAdapter(List<ChatNode> chatNodes) {
    this.chatNodes = chatNodes;
}

@Override
public ChatListAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.e2_fragment_chat_list_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ChatListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ChatNode chatNode = chatNodes.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(chatNode.getName());
    holder.lastchat.setText(chatNode.getLastchat());
    holder.lastchattime.setText(chatNode.getLastchattime());
    holder.chatunread.setText(chatNode.getChatunread());
    //holder.dp.setBackground(chatNode);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chatNodes.size();
}
```

}

The ChatNode class

```
public class ChatNode {
String name, lastchat, lastchattime, chatunread, dp;

public ChatNode() {
}

public ChatNode(String name, String lastchat, String lastchattime, String chatunread, String dp) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastchat = lastchat;
    this.lastchattime = lastchattime;
    this.chatunread = chatunread;
    this.dp = dp;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastchat() {
    return lastchat;
}

public void setLastchat(String lastchat) {
    this.lastchat = lastchat;
}

public String getLastchattime() {
    return lastchattime;
}

public void setLastchattime(String lastchattime) {
    this.lastchattime = lastchattime;
}

public String getChatunread() {
    return chatunread;
}

public void setChatunread(String chatunread) {
    this.chatunread = chatunread;
}

public String getDp() {
    return dp;
}

public void setDp(String dp) {
    this.dp = dp;
}
```

}

The Layout File

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/channel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textChannel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Channel"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listviewChannel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

And this happens to be the list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_lastChat_Hidden"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dp_placeholder"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastChat_Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Full Name"
                android:textColor="#181717"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastChat_MessageDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Sent Date"
                android:textColor="#807474"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastChat_Message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Message..."
                android:textColor="#807474"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chat_unread"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#807474"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: should use activity context `RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(YourActivity.this);`

Comment: no, same still... the view is not populated

Comment: looks alright to me.

Comment: looks pretty muck OK to me too(after all debugging procedures)... don't know why then its still not working...

Comment: try match_parent for recyclerview width and height. but the code looks fine to me.

Comment: man, that worked...that worked... such a silly thing, that ate my 40-50 hrs... Thank you, thank you very much

Comment: Additional Info (for those who may come late to this party for the same trouble), "Still its showing, no adapter attached, but working fine"

Comment: you can solve that by setting adapter after setting layout manager. you can then create setList in adapter. add chat items to chatnodes there. and call notidatasetcahnged

Comment: no issues...i just wrote that comment for someone else, so that they may not waste their precious time for such a silly issue